# Помогите разобраться в работе скриптов нового шаблона магазина 1С Битрикс 14.x

Tags: ооп, php, javascript, битрикс

Не могу понять, как организованно взаимодействие с JS объектом в шаблоне интернет-магазина новой версии CMS 1С Битрикс.

Вот тут http://hp.astormedia.ru/ я развернул стандартный магазин на 1С Битрикс 14.x. Большая часть кнопок (купить,+,- и пр.) работают через Ajax используя создаваемые в процессе формирования страницы JavaScript объекты класса JCCatalogSection (их можно увидеть в коде) вот тут пример http://hp.astormedia.ru/object.txt (примеры размещаю в файлах т.е. коды очень большие).

А вот тут JS код самого класса http://hp.astormedia.ru/class.txt . Может быть я что-то не понимаю в ООП но до меня никак не дойдёт как например вызывается метод JCCatalogSection.prototype.QuantityUp по нажатию на кнопку '+' (когда увеличиваем количество товара перед добавлением в корзину) если в коде самой ссылки нет никакого явного вызова этого метода

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="bx_bt_white bx_small" href="javascript:void(0)" id="bx_2647885750_4_quant_up">+</a>
```

единственное что вызывает подозрения - это ID этой ссылки, оно состоит из имени объекта с суффиксом quant_up, а в href просто прописан javascript:void(0). Я привык к jquery где там явно есть $('ID_элемента').Click(тут функция что по клику должно случиться). А вот как это взаимодействие организовано тут - не пойму. Объясните, подскажите, скиньте ссылку что почитать.

Comment: ну вообще оно так и есть, видимо гдето в .js файлах при загрузке страницы вешается обработчик, по другому никак. можете попробовать поиском поискать по файлам текст `quant_up`

Comment: едрён батон! А это не вот это ли кусок кода 'QUANTITY_UP_ID':'bx_2647885750_4_quant_up' - это из объекта http://hp.astormedia.ru/object.txt - где bx_2647885750_4_quant_up совпадает с тем что в ID ссылки.

Comment: Точно! Вот по моему это оно: 

BX.bind(this.obQuantityUp, 'click', BX.delegate(this.QuantityUp, this));

это код из класса т.е. при клике на этот элемент через delegate вызывается QuantityUp. От намудрили битриксойды!

Comment: да, они такие :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я во всём разобрался, на официальном форуме битрикса есть развёрнутая тема, обсуждения и файлы разобранного и прокомментированного шаблона [Кто разобрался с новым шаблоном интернет магазина на 1С Битрикс 14.x ? | 1С-Битрикс Разработчикам](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/forum6/topic61206/)